# Is there any difference between the two "エ" in 「エフェクト」?

Tags: katakana

Is there any difference between the two "エ" in 「エフェクト」? The first is bigger and the latter seems smaller.

Answer (score 5):

The smaller ェ is used in combination with フ, thus making フェ (fe).

Have a look at katakana combinations:
http://nihongo.as.ua.edu/katakana.htm

Comment: BTW, if anyone is wondering how to type ぇ or ェ instead of え or エ in an IME (wihout preceding characters); hit the x-key before pressing the e-key.